# C# How to get a text from a TextBox in Form1 and set it in Form2

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I want to make a form that is named "Settings", and in that form you can set your name. I want that after user has set his name, in Form1 there is a label that says "Welcome, " + the name that was set in Form2 (the settings form).

Comment: is this in asp.net or windows forms?

Comment: My app is windows forms

Comment: Either create a data only class that you create in one Form **and pass the instance to the other** or you pass an instance of the Form itself.

Answer (score 1):

In form2 set new property Name

```
public string Name {get; set;}
```

in Form1 you can then call this property.

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
form.ShowDialog();
string name = form.Name;
Textbox1.Text = name;
```

Comment: When i click the close button after seting the name it put " " i don't know how to get the name from the textbox my textbox name is textbox1

Comment: You must have added a `TextBox` to `Form2`. Are you setting the `Name` property in `Form2` to the value of the `Text` property of the `TextBox` before you close `Form2`?

Comment: How do i set it to the TextBox text?

Comment: In FORM2 you need textbox and button. On button add click event, then Name=textbox1.text; this.close();

Answer (score 0):

First store the name in a variable "Name". Then you can access the variable as an attribute of the class Form2 from Form1 like so:

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
newform1variable = form.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use session Session["SomeText"]=txtboxID.Text;

Retrieve session

if(Session["SomeText"]!=null) { string strSessionValue=Session["SomeText"].ToString(); }

Comment: It is WinForms question not an Asp.Net one.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO developing Windows Forms Applications using just Windows Forms leads to tightly coupled spaghetti code.

One should take advantage of modern programming techniques and patterns to have loosely coupled forms, services and data.

Form1 doesn't have to know Form2 internals to be able to show the user name when user name is changed on Form2. This can be accomplished using Event Broker technique. [This article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30066/EventBroker-a-notification-component-for-synchrono) in code project shows you an example implementation of Event Broker.

SettingsForm should be able to edit the Settings object and publish SettingsChanged event to Event Broker when setting are changed. But SettingsForm should not expose its own controls to outside.

Other forms should be able to access Settings object using dependecy injection and subscribe to SettingsChanged event so they can update their UI when settings change